# How to restyle Json from wikipedia api in mobile app?

Tags: css, ios, json, api, wikipedia

I'd like to restyle *part* of wikipedia articles and embed these parts into mobile app.

I tried to use 
`http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=New_York`
 but text in json files contains formatting for mediawiki.

How to maintain links to other pages without a mediawiki platform, so that they are displayed within the mobile (or web) app?
e.g.

e.g.

```
<a href="/wiki/Wikipedia:IPA_for _English # Key" title="Wikipedia:IPA \
for English">
```

Comment: Can't you just create your app so that `http://myapp.com/wiki/Article` shows the article?

Comment: I thought you're creating a website, so I used myapp.com to indicate the domain of your application.

Comment: sorry for long-term not replying - thank you svick, it was actually obvious. I will try to use the api and to style the page with css

Answer (score 0):

hehe, yes, this was one of my first questions when I did not know about programming with javascript.
It is funny how questions are posed when beginner :)
Here and then I will go back to old questions of mine and answer them if something useful to share.

To answer my own question:
it is possible to **hijack a link**.

using jquery here for simplicity, it is possible to select `<a>` tags that have a pattern and then bind a function to them.

Example:

```
$("a[href*='/wiki/']").click(function(e){
  // capture the link 
var link  = this.href;
// do something else..
}
```